# VB.net Active Directory get description value of attribute for group

Tags: vb.net, attributes

I am trying to get the value of description from an AD group, I can use AD to view the values individually but I'm writing a small app which lists all groups and descriptions for an individual user.

Image showing the field I wish to extract data from

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

Dim de As New DirectoryEntry()
        de.Path = "LDAP://{domain}"

```
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(de)


    searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))", {search string for target user})
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(New String() {"memberOf"})
```

Dim results As SearchResultCollection = Nothing

```
Try
        results = searcher.FindAll()

        If (results.Count > 0) Then
            Dim result As SearchResult = results(0)
            For Each role As String In result.Properties("memberOf")
        If role.StartsWith("CN=RG_") Then
```

{it is here I would want to retrieve the description value}

```
            End If
            Next
        End If
Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        If (Not results Is Nothing) Then
            results.Dispose()
        End If
        searcher.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a break form looking at the screen and while doing another mundane task I figured out that I was being stupid. The answer was simple ... I was searching against the wrong object class:

```
    searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=group)(CN=" & groupname & "))".Replace("\", "\\"))
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(New String() {"description"})
```

So, I search against the user, for each group returned if I want the description I simply run another query with the new filter.